Assistance Needed: Converting Google Guice Framework to Spring Framework
I'm currently working on a project that uses the Google Guice framework for dependency injection. However, due to various reasons, we've decided to migrate to the Spring Framework.
I'm looking for guidance on how to effectively translate the configuration and usage of Google Guice to Spring in a proper format. Specifically, I need assistance with:
Translating Guice modules to Spring configuration classes or XML files.
Converting Guice @Inject annotations to Spring's @Autowired annotations.
Handling scopes and lifecycle management differences between Guice and Spring.
Managing dependency injection in servlets and other web components.
If anyone has experience with migrating from Google Guice to Spring or can provide resources, tips, or best practices for this process, I would greatly appreciate the assistance.
Thank you in advance for your help!
